# Initialization of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, initialization

I got a school project where I need to sort numbers using linked list. I had some trouble initializing my linked list and someone gave me the folllowing solution, but I don't really understand what is happening on a line and I would like some enlightenment.

Here's the full function :

```
void stack_ini(t_lst **list_ptr, char **nbr)
{
    for (; *nbr; ++nbr)
    {
        // Create a new node.
        t_lst *node = malloc(sizeof(t_lst));
        node->content = ft_atoi(*nbr);
        node->next = NULL;

        // Insert it into the list.
        *list_ptr = node;
        list_ptr = &node->next;
    }
}
```

To complete, here's the t_lst struct :

```
typedef struct s_lst
{
    int             content;
    int             position;
    int             index;
    struct s_lst    *next;
}   t_lst;
```

I pretty much understand everything that's happening before the last line :

`list_ptr = &node->next;`

I dont get why I need to assign list_ptr to the adress of node->next. Isnt node->next supposed to be uninitialized and thus provoke a segfault ?
Also, if node and list_ptr are unassigned to their ...->next, shouldnt it just be like overwritting their current value ?

Sorry for my english and thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that initially the pointer to the head node declared in main is set to NULL something like

```
t_lst *head = NULL;
```

This pointer is passed to the function `stack_ini` by reference indirectly through pointer to it. So the function is declared like

```
void stack_ini(t_lst **list_ptr, char **nbr);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Dereferencing the parameter `list_ptr` the first time like `*list_ptr` we get an access to the original pointer `head` declared in main and can change it.

So within the function in the first iteration of its for loop this statement

```
    *list_ptr = node;
```

sets the original pointer `head` to the value of the pointer `node` that points to the newly allocated node..

Then the parameter `list_ptr` is set to the address of the data member `head->next` which is equivalent to using `node->next` in this statement

```
    list_ptr = &node->next;
```

So now the pointer `list_ptr` points to the data member `next` that can be changed in the next iteration of the for loop.

The data member `node->next` is initialized

```
    node->next = NULL;
```

That is in this statement

```
    list_ptr = &node->next;
```

you are not assigning the value of the data member node->next to the pointer `list_ptr`. Instead the pointer `list_ptr` points to the data member `next` of the current created node and using `list_ptr` you can change the value that data member in the next iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I pretty much understand everything that's happening before the last
> line :
>
> ```
> list_ptr = &node->next;
> ```
>
> I dont get why I need to assign list_ptr to the adress of node->next.
> Isnt node->next supposed to be uninitialized and thus provoke a
> segfault ?

No.  `node->next` is explicitly initialized to a null pointer.  Moreover, even if it were not initialized, its *address* (`&node->next`) is well defined. That can be computed regardless of the initialization status or value of `node->next`.

*Dereferencing* `node->next` at that point (`*node->next`) would produce undefined behavior as a result of its value being a null pointer, and that might very well manifest as the program crashing with a segfault, but no dereference is being performed.

> Also, if node and list_ptr are unassigned to their
> ...->next, shouldnt it just be like overwritting their current value ?

After adding a node, `list_ptr` is set to point to that node's `next` member, whose value is initially null.  Then when the next node is created, a pointer to it is assigned through `list_ptr` to the (then-)previous node's `next`.  Afterward, the cycle repeats, starting with updating `list_ptr` to point to the `next` member of the most recently added node.

So yes, assigning through `list_ptr` does replace the value of the pointer to which it points, but that happens at most once for each node, because after that update, `list_ptr` is itself updated to point to the `next` member of a different node.